# How to validate Entity form field using yml in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I got following error message when I tried to validate entity type form filed using validation.yml file

Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\StudentRegistration::setIdState() must be an instance of Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterState, null given, called in C:\wamp\www\careerguide\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Util\PropertyPath.php on line 347 and defined in C:\wamp\www\careerguide\src\Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\StudentRegistration.php line 1099

in form,

->add('idState', 'entity', array('class' => 'Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterState', 'property' => 'stateName', 'empty_value' => 'Select State', 'label' => 'State :', 'attr' => array('class' => 'width275'), 'required' => false))

In entity,

```
 <?php
```

namespace Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\StudentRegistration
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="student_registration")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class StudentRegistration
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

```
/**
 * @var string $idStudentRegistration
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_student_registration", type="string", length=128, nullable=false)
 */
private $idStudentRegistration;

/**
 * @var integer $idAttempt
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_attempt", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $idAttempt;

/**
 * @var string $firstName
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=128, nullable=false)
 */
private $firstName;

/**
 * @var string $lastName
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=128, nullable=true)
 */
private $lastName;

/**
 * @var datetime $dateOfBirth
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date_of_birth", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $dateOfBirth;

/**
 * @var string $gender
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="gender", type="string", length=16, nullable=true)
 */
private $gender;

/**
 * @var string $email
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=128, nullable=true)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @var string $password
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=128, nullable=true)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @var string $mobileNumber
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mobile_number", type="string", length=16, nullable=true)
 */
private $mobileNumber;

/**
 * @var string $stdCode
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="std_code", type="string", length=16, nullable=true)
 */
private $stdCode;

/**
 * @var integer $landlineNumber
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="landline_number", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $landlineNumber;

/**
 * @var text $address
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $address;

/**
 * @var integer $pincode
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="pincode", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $pincode;

/**
 * @var string $disabilityPercentage
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="disability_percentage", type="string", length=16, nullable=true)
 */
private $disabilityPercentage;

/**
 * @var string $schoolName
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="school_name", type="string", length=256, nullable=true)
 */
private $schoolName;

/**
 * @var string $collegeName
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="college_name", type="string", length=256, nullable=true)
 */
private $collegeName;

/**
 * @var string $qualificationStatus
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="qualification_status", type="string", length=128, nullable=true)
 */
private $qualificationStatus;

/**
 * @var string $courseDuration
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="course_duration", type="string", length=16, nullable=true)
 */
private $courseDuration;

/**
 * @var string $workExposure
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="work_exposure", type="string", length=16, nullable=true)
 */
private $workExposure;

/**
 * @var string $userStudyDuration
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="user_study_duration", type="string", length=16, nullable=true)
 */
private $userStudyDuration;

/**
 * @var text $achievements
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="achievements", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $achievements;

/**
 * @var datetime $createdAt
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $createdAt;

/**
 * @var datetime $updatedAt
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $updatedAt;

/**
 * @var integer $version
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="version", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $version;

/**
 * @var MasterCity
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MasterCity")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_city", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idCity;

/**
 * @var MasterStreamgroup
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MasterStreamgroup")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_streamgroup", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idStreamgroup;

/**
 * @var MasterQualification
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MasterQualification")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_qualification_father", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idQualificationFather;

/**
 * @var MasterOccupation
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MasterOccupation")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_occupation_father", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idOccupationFather;

/**
 * @var MasterQualification
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MasterQualification")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_qualification_mother", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idQualificationMother;

/**
 * @var MasterOccupation
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MasterOccupation")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_occupation_mother", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idOccupationMother;

/**
 * @var MasterCity
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MasterCity")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_preferred_city1", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idPreferredCity1;

/**
 * @var MasterCity
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MasterCity")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_preferred_city2", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idPreferredCity2;

/**
 * @var MasterCity
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MasterCity")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_preferred_city3", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idPreferredCity3;

/**
 * @var MasterBudget
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MasterBudget")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_budget", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idBudget;

/**
 * @var MasterMode
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MasterMode")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_mode", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idMode;

/**
 * @var MasterState
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MasterState")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_state", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idState;

/**
 * @var MasterCountry
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MasterCountry")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_country", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idCountry;

/**
 * @var MasterHealth
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MasterHealth")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_health", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idHealth;

/**
 * @var MasterQualification
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MasterQualification")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_qualification", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idQualification;

/**
 * @var MasterMedium
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MasterMedium")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_medium", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idMedium;

/**
 * @var MasterBoard
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MasterBoard")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_board", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idBoard;

/**
 * @var MasterUniversity
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MasterUniversity")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_university", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idUniversity;

/**
 * @var MasterStream
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MasterStream")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_stream", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idStream;



/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set idStudentRegistration
 *
 * @param string $idStudentRegistration
 */
public function setIdStudentRegistration($idStudentRegistration)
{
    $this->idStudentRegistration = $idStudentRegistration;
}

/**
 * Get idStudentRegistration
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getIdStudentRegistration()
{
    return $this->idStudentRegistration;
}

/**
 * Set idAttempt
 *
 * @param integer $idAttempt
 */
public function setIdAttempt($idAttempt)
{
    $this->idAttempt = $idAttempt;
}

/**
 * Get idAttempt
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getIdAttempt()
{
    return $this->idAttempt;
}

/**
 * Set firstName
 *
 * @param string $firstName
 */
public function setFirstName($firstName)
{
    $this->firstName = $firstName;
}

/**
 * Get firstName
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFirstName()
{
    return $this->firstName;
}

/**
 * Set lastName
 *
 * @param string $lastName
 */
public function setLastName($lastName)
{
    $this->lastName = $lastName;
}

/**
 * Get lastName
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLastName()
{
    return $this->lastName;
}

/**
 * Set dateOfBirth
 *
 * @param datetime $dateOfBirth
 */
public function setDateOfBirth($dateOfBirth)
{
    $this->dateOfBirth = $dateOfBirth;
}

/**
 * Get dateOfBirth
 *
 * @return datetime
 */
public function getDateOfBirth()
{
    return $this->dateOfBirth;
}

/**
 * Set gender
 *
 * @param string $gender
 */
public function setGender($gender)
{
    $this->gender = $gender;
}

/**
 * Get gender
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getGender()
{
    return $this->gender;
}

/**
 * Set email
 *
 * @param string $email
 */
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;
}

/**
 * Get email
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * Set password
 *
 * @param string $password
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;
}

/**
 * Get password
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Set mobileNumber
 *
 * @param string $mobileNumber
 */
public function setMobileNumber($mobileNumber)
{
    $this->mobileNumber = $mobileNumber;
}

/**
 * Get mobileNumber
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getMobileNumber()
{
    return $this->mobileNumber;
}

/**
 * Set stdCode
 *
 * @param string $stdCode
 */
public function setStdCode($stdCode)
{
    $this->stdCode = $stdCode;
}

/**
 * Get stdCode
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getStdCode()
{
    return $this->stdCode;
}

/**
 * Set landlineNumber
 *
 * @param integer $landlineNumber
 */
public function setLandlineNumber($landlineNumber)
{
    $this->landlineNumber = $landlineNumber;
}

/**
 * Get landlineNumber
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getLandlineNumber()
{
    return $this->landlineNumber;
}

/**
 * Set address
 *
 * @param text $address
 */
public function setAddress($address)
{
    $this->address = $address;
}

/**
 * Get address
 *
 * @return text
 */
public function getAddress()
{
    return $this->address;
}

/**
 * Set pincode
 *
 * @param integer $pincode
 */
public function setPincode($pincode)
{
    $this->pincode = $pincode;
}

/**
 * Get pincode
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getPincode()
{
    return $this->pincode;
}

/**
 * Set disabilityPercentage
 *
 * @param string $disabilityPercentage
 */
public function setDisabilityPercentage($disabilityPercentage)
{
    $this->disabilityPercentage = $disabilityPercentage;
}

/**
 * Get disabilityPercentage
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDisabilityPercentage()
{
    return $this->disabilityPercentage;
}

/**
 * Set schoolName
 *
 * @param string $schoolName
 */
public function setSchoolName($schoolName)
{
    $this->schoolName = $schoolName;
}

/**
 * Get schoolName
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSchoolName()
{
    return $this->schoolName;
}

/**
 * Set collegeName
 *
 * @param string $collegeName
 */
public function setCollegeName($collegeName)
{
    $this->collegeName = $collegeName;
}

/**
 * Get collegeName
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCollegeName()
{
    return $this->collegeName;
}

/**
 * Set qualificationStatus
 *
 * @param string $qualificationStatus
 */
public function setQualificationStatus($qualificationStatus)
{
    $this->qualificationStatus = $qualificationStatus;
}

/**
 * Get qualificationStatus
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getQualificationStatus()
{
    return $this->qualificationStatus;
}

/**
 * Set courseDuration
 *
 * @param string $courseDuration
 */
public function setCourseDuration($courseDuration)
{
    $this->courseDuration = $courseDuration;
}

/**
 * Get courseDuration
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCourseDuration()
{
    return $this->courseDuration;
}

/**
 * Set workExposure
 *
 * @param string $workExposure
 */
public function setWorkExposure($workExposure)
{
    $this->workExposure = $workExposure;
}

/**
 * Get workExposure
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getWorkExposure()
{
    return $this->workExposure;
}

/**
 * Set userStudyDuration
 *
 * @param string $userStudyDuration
 */
public function setUserStudyDuration($userStudyDuration)
{
    $this->userStudyDuration = $userStudyDuration;
}

/**
 * Get userStudyDuration
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getUserStudyDuration()
{
    return $this->userStudyDuration;
}

/**
 * Set achievements
 *
 * @param text $achievements
 */
public function setAchievements($achievements)
{
    $this->achievements = $achievements;
}

/**
 * Get achievements
 *
 * @return text
 */
public function getAchievements()
{
    return $this->achievements;
}

/**
 * Set createdAt
 *
 * @param datetime $createdAt
 */
public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
{
    $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
}

/**
 * Get createdAt
 *
 * @return datetime
 */
public function getCreatedAt()
{
    return $this->createdAt;
}

/**
 * Set updatedAt
 *
 * @param datetime $updatedAt
 */
public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
{
    $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;
}

/**
 * Get updatedAt
 *
 * @return datetime
 */
public function getUpdatedAt()
{
    return $this->updatedAt;
}

/**
 * Set version
 *
 * @param integer $version
 */
public function setVersion($version)
{
    $this->version = $version;
}

/**
 * Get version
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getVersion()
{
    return $this->version;
}

/**
 * Set idCity
 *
 * @param Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterCity $idCity
 */
public function setIdCity(\Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterCity $idCity)
{
    $this->idCity = $idCity;
}

/**
 * Get idCity
 *
 * @return Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterCity
 */
public function getIdCity()
{
    return $this->idCity;
}

/**
 * Set idStreamgroup
 *
 * @param Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterStreamgroup $idStreamgroup
 */
public function setIdStreamgroup(\Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterStreamgroup $idStreamgroup)
{
    $this->idStreamgroup = $idStreamgroup;
}

/**
 * Get idStreamgroup
 *
 * @return Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterStreamgroup
 */
public function getIdStreamgroup()
{
    return $this->idStreamgroup;
}

/**
 * Set idQualificationFather
 *
 * @param Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterQualification $idQualificationFather
 */
public function setIdQualificationFather(\Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterQualification $idQualificationFather)
{
    $this->idQualificationFather = $idQualificationFather;
}

/**
 * Get idQualificationFather
 *
 * @return Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterQualification
 */
public function getIdQualificationFather()
{
    return $this->idQualificationFather;
}

/**
 * Set idOccupationFather
 *
 * @param Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterOccupation $idOccupationFather
 */
public function setIdOccupationFather(\Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterOccupation $idOccupationFather)
{
    $this->idOccupationFather = $idOccupationFather;
}

/**
 * Get idOccupationFather
 *
 * @return Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterOccupation
 */
public function getIdOccupationFather()
{
    return $this->idOccupationFather;
}

/**
 * Set idQualificationMother
 *
 * @param Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterQualification $idQualificationMother
 */
public function setIdQualificationMother(\Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterQualification $idQualificationMother)
{
    $this->idQualificationMother = $idQualificationMother;
}

/**
 * Get idQualificationMother
 *
 * @return Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterQualification
 */
public function getIdQualificationMother()
{
    return $this->idQualificationMother;
}

/**
 * Set idOccupationMother
 *
 * @param Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterOccupation $idOccupationMother
 */
public function setIdOccupationMother(\Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterOccupation $idOccupationMother)
{
    $this->idOccupationMother = $idOccupationMother;
}

/**
 * Get idOccupationMother
 *
 * @return Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterOccupation
 */
public function getIdOccupationMother()
{
    return $this->idOccupationMother;
}

/**
 * Set idPreferredCity1
 *
 * @param Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterCity $idPreferredCity1
 */
public function setIdPreferredCity1(\Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterCity $idPreferredCity1)
{
    $this->idPreferredCity1 = $idPreferredCity1;
}

/**
 * Get idPreferredCity1
 *
 * @return Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterCity
 */
public function getIdPreferredCity1()
{
    return $this->idPreferredCity1;
}

/**
 * Set idPreferredCity2
 *
 * @param Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterCity $idPreferredCity2
 */
public function setIdPreferredCity2(\Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterCity $idPreferredCity2)
{
    $this->idPreferredCity2 = $idPreferredCity2;
}

/**
 * Get idPreferredCity2
 *
 * @return Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterCity
 */
public function getIdPreferredCity2()
{
    return $this->idPreferredCity2;
}

/**
 * Set idPreferredCity3
 *
 * @param Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterCity $idPreferredCity3
 */
public function setIdPreferredCity3(\Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterCity $idPreferredCity3)
{
    $this->idPreferredCity3 = $idPreferredCity3;
}

/**
 * Get idPreferredCity3
 *
 * @return Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterCity
 */
public function getIdPreferredCity3()
{
    return $this->idPreferredCity3;
}

/**
 * Set idBudget
 *
 * @param Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterBudget $idBudget
 */
public function setIdBudget(\Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterBudget $idBudget)
{
    $this->idBudget = $idBudget;
}

/**
 * Get idBudget
 *
 * @return Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterBudget
 */
public function getIdBudget()
{
    return $this->idBudget;
}

/**
 * Set idMode
 *
 * @param Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterMode $idMode
 */
public function setIdMode(\Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterMode $idMode)
{
    $this->idMode = $idMode;
}

/**
 * Get idMode
 *
 * @return Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterMode
 */
public function getIdMode()
{
    return $this->idMode;
}

/**
 * Set idState
 *
 * @param Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterState $idState
 */
public function setIdState(\Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterState $idState)
{
    $this->idState = $idState;
}

/**
 * Get idState
 *
 * @return Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterState
 */
public function getIdState()
{
    return $this->idState;
}

/**
 * Set idCountry
 *
 * @param Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterCountry $idCountry
 */
public function setIdCountry(\Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterCountry $idCountry)
{
    $this->idCountry = $idCountry;
}

/**
 * Get idCountry
 *
 * @return Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterCountry
 */
public function getIdCountry()
{
    return $this->idCountry;
}

/**
 * Set idHealth
 *
 * @param Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterHealth $idHealth
 */
public function setIdHealth(\Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterHealth $idHealth)
{
    $this->idHealth = $idHealth;
}

/**
 * Get idHealth
 *
 * @return Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterHealth
 */
public function getIdHealth()
{
    return $this->idHealth;
}

/**
 * Set idQualification
 *
 * @param Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterQualification $idQualification
 */
public function setIdQualification(\Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterQualification $idQualification)
{
    $this->idQualification = $idQualification;
}

/**
 * Get idQualification
 *
 * @return Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterQualification
 */
public function getIdQualification()
{
    return $this->idQualification;
}

/**
 * Set idMedium
 *
 * @param Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterMedium $idMedium
 */
public function setIdMedium(\Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterMedium $idMedium)
{
    $this->idMedium = $idMedium;
}

/**
 * Get idMedium
 *
 * @return Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterMedium
 */
public function getIdMedium()
{
    return $this->idMedium;
}

/**
 * Set idBoard
 *
 * @param Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterBoard $idBoard
 */
public function setIdBoard(\Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterBoard $idBoard)
{
    $this->idBoard = $idBoard;
}

/**
 * Get idBoard
 *
 * @return Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterBoard
 */
public function getIdBoard()
{
    return $this->idBoard;
}

/**
 * Set idUniversity
 *
 * @param Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterUniversity $idUniversity
 */
public function setIdUniversity(\Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterUniversity $idUniversity)
{
    $this->idUniversity = $idUniversity;
}

/**
 * Get idUniversity
 *
 * @return Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterUniversity
 */
public function getIdUniversity()
{
    return $this->idUniversity;
}

/**
 * Set idStream
 *
 * @param Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterStream $idStream
 */
public function setIdStream(\Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterStream $idStream)
{
    $this->idStream = $idStream;
}

/**
 * Get idStream
 *
 * @return Frontend\EntityBundle\Entity\MasterStream
 */
public function getIdStream()
{
    return $this->idStream;
}
```

}

and in validation.yml

idState:
   - NotBlank: { message: "Please select state.", groups: [ personalDetails ] }

Comment: could y paste whole StudentRegistration ?

Comment: @ Parhs: Thank you for reply, i updated question as per requirements.